# Does Craft work with PHP 7?

Tags: php, server

I'm attempting to run Craft (2.4.2696) on a server with PHP 7 RC, and I'm seeing [the following PHP warning](http://cly.mmikkel.no/image/310E1X203U0Y):

`Declaration of Craft\DbCommand::addForeignKey($table, $columns, $refTable, $refColumns, $delete = NULL, $update = NULL) should be compatible with CDbCommand::addForeignKey($name, $table, $columns, $refTable, $refColumns, $delete = NULL, $update = NULL)`

It's only a warning, and with `devMode` off, the site seems to function well. I'm not going to put anything that throws warnings into production, though.

My question(s): What is the cause for this warning, and is it something I can fix myself? Does Craft officially support PHP 7?

Comment: Looks like PHP 7 reclassified some error messages from E_STRICT to E_WARNING (including this one): https://wiki.php.net/rfc/reclassify_e_strict#signature_mismatch_during_inheritance Will update with an answer if I can think of a clean solution.

Comment: Sweet, thanks @BradBell. I can revert to 5.6 but it would be fun to play around with 7. Also interested in knowing whether Craft 2.x officially supports 7 or if its too early yet. The docs doesn't mention it at all.

Comment: FWIW Craft 3 doesn't have this issue, too.

Comment: Good to know ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @mmikkel pointed out, as of [Craft 2.4.2697](http://buildwithcraft.com/updates#build2697), Craft is PHP 7 compatible.

Comment: [Craft 2.4.2697 is out, adding PHP 7 compatibility](http://buildwithcraft.com/updates#build2697).

Comment: [Craft 2.7](https://craftcms.com/news/craft-2-7) also has PHP 7.2 support.